# discard lines containing specific characters

Tags: bash, text

How can I delete the lines from a file containing the character 'H'?
The file contains the following column:

```
H1
N1
H2
C1
H3
H4
C2
H5
H6
N2
H7
C3
H8
H9
C4
H10
H11
N3
H12
C5
H13
H14
C6
H15
H16
```

Desired output is:

```
N1
C1
C2
N2
C3
C4
N3
C5
C6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dr01 gave a great answer using `grep`, you can also use `sed`, and some `sed` implementations also have a `-i` option that allows you to edit files in-place without the need to use redirection,

```
sed -i /H/d file.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Easily:

```
grep -v 'H' oldfile > newfile
```

For more info, see the grep manpage:

```
man grep
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course `awk` will work too:

```
awk '!/H/' oldfile > newfile
```